# How can i convert a localhost webiste project into Android Web Apllication usinga Html css Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, web-applications

can anyone suggest to me a code to build Android Web-Application using HTML, CSS, javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Create a **progressive web app** with **angular**. the serviceworker does all the work anyway to then be able to use the web app as a pwa.